# Artifactory and Tomcat

Tags: artifactory, weblogic12c, jfrog-cli

I'm running the artifactory.sh in linux and I can successfully deploy the app. However, I can't open it with https://localhost:8080/artifactory/webapp or https://localhost:8080/artifactory/ . I also tried changing 8080 t0 8081 but no success. I running the latest version of artifactory as standalone

```
                _   _  __           _                      ____   _____ _____
     /\        | | (_)/ _|         | |                    / __ \ / ____/ ____|
    /  \   _ __| |_ _| |_ __ _  ___| |_ ___  _ __ _   _  | |  | | (___| (___
   / /\ \ | '__| __| |  _/ _` |/ __| __/ _ \| '__| | | | | |  | |\___ \\___ \
  / ____ \| |  | |_| | || (_| | (__| || (_) | |  | |_| | | |__| |____) |___) |
 /_/    \_\_|   \__|_|_| \__,_|\___|\__\___/|_|   \__, |  \____/|_____/_____/
 Version:  5.8.3                                   __/ |
 Revision: 50803900                               |___/
 Artifactory Home: '/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory'


2018-02-08 21:30:10,419 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.r.c.RpcServiceInvoker:86) - Added service: sync
2018-02-08 21:30:10,624 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:93) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access bootstrap...
2018-02-08 21:30:11,391 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:146) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Updating server '44279303-8cf3-496a-8355-81f987936495' private key finger print to: 96f5a8dbaa0963102d654b6e06b6d3a477a39b65da392e73e81adc76fa3a2a2a
2018-02-08 21:30:11,794 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:108) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] JFrog Access bootstrap finished.
2018-02-08 21:30:12,260 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:556) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled) source: detected
2018-02-08 21:30:12,416 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:275) - Waiting for access server...
2018-02-08 21:30:13,272 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.s.s.RefreshableScheduledJob:56) - Scheduling heartbeat task to run every 5 seconds
2018-02-08 21:30:15,468 [localhost-startStop-1] [JFrog-Access] [INFO ] (o.j.a.AccessApplication:57) - Started AccessApplication in 15.473 seconds (JVM running for 16.895)
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor [/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [16,352] ms
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory [/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [16] ms
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8040"]
Feb 08, 2018 9:30:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
2018-02-08 21:30:16,504 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:285) - Got response from Access server after 4087 ms, continuing.
2018-02-08 21:30:16,735 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:266) - Initialized access service successfully with client id 1088765704, closing old client id [null]
2018-02-08 21:30:16,735 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:986) - Updating access configuration with password expiration data
2018-02-08 21:30:17,718 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.i.InfoWriter    :87) -

   artifactory.mvn.metadata.plugin.calculation.workers                   | 2
   artifactory.mvn.metadata.calculation.workers                          | 8
   artifactory.mvn.dynamicMetadata.cacheRetentionSecs                    | 10
   artifactory.mvn.metadata.version3.enabled                             | true
   artifactory.mvn.custom.types                                          | tar.gz,tar.bz2
   artifactory.request.disableVersionTokens                              | false
   artifactory.request.searchLatestReleaseByDateCreated                  | false
   artifactory.npm.tag.tagLatestByPublish                                | false
   artifactory.build.maxFoldersToScanForDeletionWarnings                 | 2
   artifactory.build.checksum.cache.idleTimeSecs                         | 300
   artifactory.updates.refreshIntervalSecs                               | 14400
   artifactory.updates.url                                               | http://service.jfrog.org/artifactory/updates
   artifactory.artifactoryRequestsToGlobalCanRetrieveRemoteArtifacts     | false
   artifactory.ui.syntaxColoringMaxTextSizeBytes                         | 512000
   artifactory.plugin.scripts.refreshIntervalSecs                        | 0
   artifactory.plugin.aol.support                                        | false
   artifactory.aol.dedicated.server                                      | false
   artifactory.aol.displayAccountManagementLink                          | true
   artifactory.aol.security.http.sso.enable                              | false
   artifactory.ui.session.timeout.minutes                                | 30
   artifactory.file.roller.maxFileToRetain                               | 10
   artifactory.backup.fileExportSleepIterationMillis                     | 2000
   artifactory.backup.fileExportSleepMillis                              | 250
   artifactory.s3.existsCheckAfterAddingStream                           | true
   artifactory.http.acceptEncoding.gzip                                  | true
   artifactory.http.useExpectContinue                                    | false
   artifactory.http.forceForbiddenResponse                               | false
   artifactory.http.connectionPool.timeToLive                            | 30
   artifactory.http.enableCookieManagement                               | false
   artifactory.filtering.resourceSizeKb                                  | 64
   artifactory.repo.remote.checkForExistingResourceOnRequest             | true
   artifactory.version.query.enabled                                     | true
   artifactory.response.disableContentDispositionFilename                | false
   artifactory.composer.metadata.extractor.workers                       | 20
   artifactory.composer.metadata.index.workers                           | 10
   artifactory.chef.metadata.index.workers                               | 10
   artifactory.yum.virtual.metadata.calculation.workers                  | 5
   artifactory.rpm.metadata.calculation.workers                          | 8
   artifactory.rpm.metadata.history.cycles.to.keep                       | 3
   artifactory.debian.metadata.calculation.workers                       | 8
   artifactory.debian.remote.etag                                        | true
   artifactory.debian.metadata.validation                                | true
   artifactory.debian.metadata.calculateMd5InPackagesFiles               | false
   artifactory.debian.use.acquire.byhash                                 | true
   artifactory.debian.packages.byhash.history.cycles.to.Keep             | 3
   artifactory.archive.licenseFile.names                                 | license,LICENSE,license.txt,LICENSE.txt,LICENSE.TXT
   artifactory.ui.search.maxRowsPerPage                                  | 20
   artifactory.replication.checksumDeploy.minSizeKb                      | 10
   artifactory.replication.consumer.queueSize                            | 1
   artifactory.replication.local.iteration.sleepThresholdMillis          | 1000
   artifactory.replication.local.iteration.sleepMillis                   | 100
   artifactory.replication.event.queue.size                              | 50000
   artifactory.replication.properties.max.length                         | 100000
   artifactory.replication.statistics.max.length                         | 5000
   artifactory.replication.initContext.task.intervalSecs                 | 60
   artifactory.replication.initContext.task.initialDelaySecs             | 5
   artifactory.request.explodedArchiveExtensions                         | zip,tar,tar.gz,tgz
   artifactory.bintray.jcenter.url                                       | http://jcenter.bintray.com
   artifactory.bintray.url                                               | https://bintray.com
   artifactory.bintray.api.url                                           | https://api.bintray.com
   artifactory.bintray.token.expirySecs                                  | 3600
   artifactory.bintray.distributionRegex.timeoutMillis                   | 180000
   artifactory.bintray.ui.hideUploads                                    | false
   artifactory.bintray.ui.hideInfo                                       | false
   artifactory.bintray.ui.hideRemoteSearch                               | false
   artifactory.bintray.client.threadPool.size                            | 5
   artifactory.enable.ui.pages.in.Iframe                                 | false
   artifactory.bintray.client.requestTimeoutMS                           | 150000
   artifactory.bintray.client.distribution.requestTimeoutMS              | 30000
   artifactory.bintray.client.signRequestTimeoutMS                       | 45000
   artifactory.useUserNameAutoCompleteOnLogin                            | on
   artifactory.ui.hideEncryptedPassword                                  | *****
   artifactory.stats.flushIntervalSecs                                   | 30
   artifactory.stats.remote.flushIntervalSecs                            | 35
   artifactory.stats.flushTimeoutSecs                                    | 120
   artifactory.integrationCleanup.intervalSecs                           | 300
   artifactory.integrationCleanup.quietPeriodSecs                        | 60
   artifactory.folderPruning.intervalSecs                                | 300
   artifactory.folderPruning.quietPeriodSecs                             | 60
   artifactory.repo.virtualCacheCleanup.maxAgeHours                      | 168
   artifactory.repo.virtualCacheCleanup.pattern                          | *.pom
   artifactory.security.authentication.password.salt                     | ****************
   artifactory.db.idGenerator.fetch.amount                               | 2000
   artifactory.db.idGenerator.max.update.retries                         | 50
   artifactory.gems.localIndexTaskIntervalSecs                           | 30
   artifactory.gems.virtualIndexTaskIntervalSecs                         | 300
   artifactory.gems.gemsIndexTaskQueueLimit                              | 20000
   artifactory.gems.gemsAfterRepoInitHack                                | true
   artifactory.security.authentication.crowd.group.startIndex            | 0
   artifactory.security.authentication.crowd.group.maxResults            | 9999
   artifactory.ui.hideChecksums                                          | true
   artifactory.archive.indexer.intervalSecs                              | 60
   artifactory.xray.indexer.intervalSecs                                 | 60
   artifactory.xray.force.reindex                                        | false
   artifactory.xray.scanBuild.httpClient.max.connections                 | 30
   artifactory.nuget.inMemoryRemoteCaches                                | true
   artifactory.nuget.forceAuthentication                                 | false
   artifactory.nuget.allowRootGetWithAnon                                | false
   artifactory.ha.heartbeat.intervalSecs                                 | 5
   artifactory.ha.heartbeat.staleSecs                                    | 30
   artifactory.ha.heartbeat.recently.worked.trigger.days                 | 7
   artifactory.ha.propagation.http.socketTimeoutMs                       | 5000
   artifactory.ha.propagation.http.connectionTimeoutMs                   | 5000
   artifactory.ha.propagation.http.maxConnectionsPerRoute                | 50
   artifactory.ha.propagation.http.maxTotalConnections                   | 150
   artifactory.ha.propagation.CallTimeoutSecs                            | 30
   artifactory.binary.store.error.notification.intervalSecs              | 30
   artifactory.binary.store.error.notification.staleSecs                 | 30
   artifactory.ha.membersIntroduction.intervalSecs                       | 30
   artifactory.ha.membersIntroduction.staleSecs                          | 30
   artifactory.npm.index.quietPeriodSecs                                 | 60
   artifactory.npm.index.cycleSecs                                       | 60
   artifactory.import.max.parallelRepos                                  | 2
   artifactory.debian.distribution.path                                  | dists
   artifactory.opkg.index.quietPeriodSecs                                | 60
   artifactory.opkg.index.cycleSecs                                      | 2
   artifactory.debian.default.architectures                              | i386,amd64
   artifactory.pypi.index.quietPeriodSecs                                | 60
   artifactory.pypi.index.sleepMilliSecs                                 | 60
   artifactory.docker.cleanup.maxAgeMillis                               | 86400000
   artifactory.docker.tags.cleanup.intervalSecs                          | 300
   artifactory.docker.tags.cleanup.quietPeriodSecs                       | 60
   artifactory.http.range.support                                        | true
   artifactory.acl.dirty.read.timeout                                    | 20000
   artifactory.central.config.dirty.read.timeout.millis                  | 2000
   artifactory.central.config.latest.revisions.expire.after.access.seconds| 21600
   artifactory.central.config.latest.revisions.dictionary.size           | 20
   artifactory.central.config.save.number.of.retries                     | 5
   artifactory.central.config.save.backoff.max.delay                     | 8000
   artifactory.central.config.save.backoff.multiplier                    | 2
   artifactory.repositories.dirty.read.timeout.millis                    | 5000
   artifactory.ping.allowUnauthenticated                                 | false
   artifactory.repo.http.idleConnectionMonitorInterval                   | 10
   artifactory.repo.http.disableIdleConnectionMonitoring                 | false
   artifactory.support.core.bundle.contentCollectionAwaitTimeout         | 60
   artifactory.support.core.bundle.waitForSlotBeforeWithdraw             | 600
   artifactory.support.core.bundle.maxBundles                            | 5
   artifactory.binary.provider.zones                                     | a,b,c
   artifactory.binary.provider.prune.chunk.size                          | 500
   artifactory.properties.search.chunk.size                              | 500
   artifactory.security.useFrontCacheForBlockedUsers                     | true
   artifactory.security.loginBlockDelay                                  | 500
   artifactory.security.password.expiry.passwordExpireNotificationJobIntervalSecs| *****
   artifactory.security.password.expiry.passwordExpireJobIntervalSecs    | *****
   artifactory.security.password.expiry.daysToNotifyBefore               | *
   artifactory.http.client.max.total.connections                         | 50
   artifactory.http.client.max.connections.per.route                     | 50
   artifactory.hazelcast.max.lock.lease.time.minutes                     | 30
   artifactory.repo.remote.blockedMismatchingMimeTypes                   | text/html,application/xhtml+xml
   artifactory.mvn.metadata.calculation.skip.delete.event                | false
   artifactory.repo.remote.browsing.content.length.limit.KB              | 1024
   artifactory.hazelcast.management                                      | false
   artifactory.hazelcast.map.max.backup.count                            | 1
   artifactory.sumologic.api.url                                         | https://auth.sumologic.com
   artifactory.move.copy.max.folder.cache.size                           | 1000000
   artifactory.move.copy.default.transaction.size                        | 1000
   artifactory.node.properties.replace.all                               | false
   artifactory.node.properties.log.performance                           | false
   artifactory.workQueue.execution.syncExecutionTimeoutMillis            | 120000
   artifactory.workQueue.dojob.intervalSecs                              | 600
   artifactory.workitem.max.lock.lease.time.minutes                      | 30
   artifactory.ha.messages.workers                                       | 10
   artifactory.security.communication.constant                           | ArtifactorySecurityCommunicationConstant
   artifactory.nuget.disablePermissionCheck                              | false
   artifactory.treebrowser.sortRepositories.sortByType                   | virtual,distribution,local,remote
   artifactory.maven.metadata.publishModelVersion                        | true
   artifactory.access.token.expiresIn.default                            | 3600
   artifactory.access.client.token.verify.result.cache.size              | -1
   artifactory.access.client.token.verify.result.cache.expiry            | -1
   artifactory.access.client.waitForServer                               | 90
   artifactory.access.client.max.connections                             | 50
   artifactory.access.client.connection.timeout                          | -1
   artifactory.access.client.socket.timeout                              | -1
   artifactory.puppet.metadata.calculation.workers                       | 5
   artifactory.puppet.repo.metadata.calculation.workers                  | 5
   artifactory.puppet.reindex.period                                     | 1800
   artifactory.puppet.additional.modulegroup                             |
   artifactory.puppet.additional.endorsement                             |
   artifactory.onboarding.skipWizard                                     | false
   artifactory.configuration.manager.retry.amount                        | 3
   artifactory.aggregation.time.window.secs                              | 60
   artifactory.most.downloaded.cache.idleTimeSecs                        | 900
   artifactory.replication.eventBased.connection.maxDelay                | 1800000
   artifactory.replications.eventbased.workers                           | 8
   artifactory.replication.eventbased.maxQueueItems                      | 500
   artifactory.build.retention.workers                                   | 10
   artifactory.build.retention.always.async                              | false
   artifactory.locking.provider.type                                     | distributed
   artifactory.map.provider.type                                         | distributed
   artifactory.db.lock.cleanup.job.interval                              | 10
   artifactory.db.lock.cleanup.job.stale.interval                        | 10
   artifactory.migration.job.waitForCluster.sleepIntervalMillis          | 300000
   artifactory.migration.job.dbQueryLimit                                | 100
   artifactory.migration.job.batchSize                                   | 10
   artifactory.migration.job.sleepIntervalMillis                         | 5000
   artifactory.sha2.migration.job.enabled                                | false
   artifactory.sha2.migration.job.queue.workers                          | 2
   artifactory.pathChecksum.migration.job.enabled                        | false
   artifactory.pathChecksum.migration.job.queue.workers                  | 2
   artifactory.upload.failOnChecksumValidationError                      | false
   artifactory.remote.download.inVain.consume.limit.inMegaBytes          | 1
   artifactory.service.name                                              | https://localhost:8080/artifactory/webapp/
   artifactory.helm.metadata.calculation.workers                         | 2
   artifactory.helm.virtual.metadata.calculation.workers                 | 2
   artifactory.helm.virtual.url.metadata.calculation.workers             | 2
   artifactory.master.key.waiting.timeout.millis                         | *****
   artifactory.bootstrap.logger.debug                                    | false
   artifactory.send.overwrites.to.trashcan                               | true
   artifactory.enable.replicator.use                                     | false
   artifactory.min.replicator.use.filesize.in.bytes                      | 1000000
   artifactory.home                                                      | /opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory

 Java System Info
 ========================
   java.class.version                                                    | 52.0
   java.home                                                             | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre
   java.io.tmpdir                                                        | /opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/temp
   java.runtime.name                                                     | Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
   java.runtime.version                                                  | 1.8.0_152-b16
   java.specification.name                                               | Java Platform API Specification
   java.specification.vendor                                             | Oracle Corporation
   java.specification.version                                            | 1.8
   java.vendor                                                           | Oracle Corporation
   java.vendor.url                                                       | http://java.oracle.com/
   java.vendor.url.bug                                                   | http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
   java.version                                                          | 1.8.0_152
   java.vm.info                                                          | mixed mode
   java.vm.name                                                          | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
   java.vm.specification.name                                            | Java Virtual Machine Specification
   java.vm.specification.vendor                                          | Oracle Corporation
   java.vm.specification.version                                         | 1.8
   java.vm.vendor                                                        | Oracle Corporation
   java.vm.version                                                       | 25.152-b16
   sun.arch.data.model                                                   | 64
   sun.boot.library.path                                                 | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/amd64
   sun.cpu.endian                                                        | little
   sun.cpu.isalist                                                       |
   sun.io.unicode.encoding                                               | UnicodeLittle
   sun.java.launcher                                                     | SUN_STANDARD
   sun.jnu.encoding                                                      | UTF-8
   sun.management.compiler                                               | HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
   sun.os.patch.level                                                    | unknown
   JVM Input arguments                                                   | -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
                                                                         | -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
                                                                         | -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=****
                                                                         | -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
                                                                         | -Xms512m
                                                                         | -Xmx2g
                                                                         | -Xss256k
                                                                         | -XX:+UseG1GC
                                                                         | -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
                                                                         | -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false
                                                                         | -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
                                                                         | -Dartdist=zip
                                                                         | -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
                                                                         | -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
                                                                         | -Dartifactory.home=/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory
                                                                         | -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
                                                                         | -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false
                                                                         | -Dcatalina.base=/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat
                                                                         | -Dcatalina.home=/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat
                                                                         | -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/temp

 Java Class Path Info
 ========================
   sun.boot.class.path                                                   | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/resources.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/rt.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/jsse.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/jce.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/charsets.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/jfr.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/classes
   java.library.path                                                     | /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
   java.endorsed.dirs                                                    | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/endorsed
   java.ext.dirs                                                         | /opt/Oracle/apps/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
   java.class.path                                                       | /opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
                                                                         | /opt/Oracle/scripts/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

2018-02-08 21:30:20,673 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.c.w.ConfigurationManagerImpl:439) - Replacing temporary DB channel with permanent DB channel
2018-02-08 21:30:20,721 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.c.w.ConfigurationManagerImpl:439) - Successfully closed temporary DB channel
2018-02-08 21:30:20,722 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:480) - Artifactory application context set to READY by refresh
2018-02-08 21:30:20,738 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:228) -
###########################################################
### Artifactory successfully started (17.452 seconds)   ###
###########################################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default artifactory port is 8081 over HTTP

So http://localhost:8081/artifactory

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. The reason behind this confusion is that the logs give you the url  https://localhost:8080/artifactory/webapp as being the service url and that threw me off course.